# oracle database change notification the partition table

Tags: java, oracle, oracle11g, oracle-rac

I have 2 node Oracle Real Application Clusters (RAC) and I connect to nodes with virtual IP.

I'm facing a problem about [Database Change Notification](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/java.112/e16548/dbchgnf.htm#JJDBC28816) the issue is when I updated data on AUTHENTICATION table some row doesn't call listener. <strike>I think I must register a listener on every partition table right?</strike>

I tried to flush the oracle buffer cache but It still not working.

My partition table

AUTHENTICATION

- AUTHENTICATION_P1
- AUTHENTICATION_P2

My java code

```
    try{
            dcr.addListener(new DatabaseChangeListener() {

                public void onDatabaseChangeNotification(DatabaseChangeEvent dce) {
                    System.out.println("Changed row id : "+dce.getTableChangeDescription()[0].getRowChangeDescription()[0].getRowid().stringValue());
                }
            });

            Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
            ((OracleStatement) stmt).setDatabaseChangeRegistration(dcr);
            ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("select * from AUTHENTICATION where rownum=1");
            while (rs.next()) {
            }
            rs.close();
            stmt.close();
        }catch(SQLException ex){
            if (conn != null)
            {
                conn.unregisterDatabaseChangeNotification(dcr);
                conn.close();
            }
            throw ex;
        }
```

**Update**
@Jean de Lavarene's mention

Yes , I can't register a listener for a specific partition.

Comment: You can't register a listener for a specific partition. How are you updating the rows? Is it through SQL or sqlloader (i.e. direct path)? Also did you make sure you committed the update?

Comment: it's updated by php application or oracleeditor php script or java application via JPA. It work fine if the table does not have partition table.